# Python: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isdir'

Tags: python

I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isdir'`
I am trying to loop through my `test` directory and check if values in my dataframe exist in there and label it with a column named status.

pl_dest is a dataframe like so:

[image]

```
test = (r'O:\Stack\Over\Flow')

for idx in pl_dest.iterrows():
        
   if pl_dest['Folder_Name_to_create'].isdir(test):
        pl_dest.loc[idx, 'status'] = 'exists'
        print('\texact folder already exists')
        continue
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you are using pathlib... is Folder_Name_to_create a column of strings or Path objects?

Comment: why do you *think* that an `.isdir(test)` method exists?

Answer (score 1):

`pl_dest['Folder_Name_to_create']` is a `pandas.Series` object and doesn't have a `isdir` method.

Instead of iterating the rows, you could use `.apply` to apply a function to each value in the column. The resulting Series would be True/False for existence. You could modify that to "exists" and "" later if you'd like. But boolean status is usually best left boolean.

The functional way to check filesystems is in the `os` module. If these were `Path` objects in the dataframe, the solution would be different.

```
import os

pl_dest['status'] = pl_dest['Folder_Name_to_create'].apply(os.path.isdir)
```

You give a function to `.apply`; it will call the function with each value of the series in turn, and create a new series with the result. In this case, `os.path.isdir` will return True/False if the path exists and is a directory, leaving you a boolean Series.

Comment: thanks for this. In your example what is `os.path.exists` referring to? It should be referring to the path in the `test` variable

Comment: @Jonnyboi - added an explanation - that function is applied to each value in the series.

Comment: thanks! but how do I check if rows in  `pl_dest['Folder_Name_to_create']`  exist in `test = (r'O:\Stack\Over\Flow')` . Can I change `os.path.exists` to my test variable?

Comment: Assuming python 3.9 plus, you could use pathlib is_relative_to. `from pathlib import Path` then `.apply(lambda path: Path(path).is_relative_to(test))`

Comment: oh no im getting an error `AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'is_relative_to'` when i use `pl_dest['status'] = pl_dest['Folder_Name_to_create'].apply(lambda path: Path(path).is_relative_to(test))` . Ah my python version is 3.8.5 .  Would `isin` be useful here?